# Finding a string based on specific criteria

Tags: c#, infopath2010

I have been trying to work in a conjunction of Infopath and C#. Part of this has involved creating a special paste button to strip out alot of HTML formatting (except maintain line breaks) from what is currently on the clipboard, but I also need to try and find a specific string within the entire body of the clipboard before it's pasted based on specific criteria. I'm trying to find any parts of the string that start with c followed by 8 digits (something like "c01234567"), so that value can be saved separately from the rest of the body of the clipboard.

```
public void PASTE_Special_Clicked(object sender, ClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        XPathNavigator Notes = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:Issue/my:I_TroubleshootingSteps", NamespaceManager);
        string ClipboardValue = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Html);
        ClipboardValue = ClipboardValue.Substring(ClipboardValue.IndexOf("</HEAD>"));
        ClipboardValue = ClipboardValue.Replace("<LI>", "&@");
        ClipboardValue = Regex.Replace(ClipboardValue, @"<[^>]*>", String.Empty);
        ClipboardValue = ClipboardValue.Replace("&@", "<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"/>");
        ClipboardValue = ClipboardValue.Replace("â€“", "-");
        Notes.AppendChild("<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"/>");
        Notes.AppendChild(ClipboardValue);
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is your question, and what problems did you encounter that make the obvious methods not suitable?